# How do I tell a topic on confluent cloud to use a specific schema programmatically?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-kafka-python

So I know how to create topics on Confluent Cloud with the confluent_kafka AdminClient instance but I’m not sure how to set the topic’s message schema programmatically? To clarify, I have the schema I want to use saved locally in an avro schema file(.avsc)

Answer (score 0):

Use the AdminClient to create the topic and then use the SchemaRegistryClient to register the schema for the topic.

Comment: any documentation on how to do this with the confluent_kafka python library? From this link, https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#schemaregistry-client, it doesn’t look like any methods support registering a schema to a specific topic

Comment: @user1943079 Because you can't. Topics dont have schemas. Only the Registry has **subjects**, which (optionally) map to topic names. You need to use HTTP clients to talk to the Registry, not Kafka clients.